# SQL - Get "records" that do NOT have matches in a list of strings I have

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a very common scenario I run into that I'm wondering if there's an easy way to solve with SQL --

I have a table with 2,000 records in it:

```
UNIVERSITY
id, name
```

So, for example:

```
1, UConn
2, Eastern
3, Western
4, Southern
```

Then someone gives me an Excel sheet with some university names in it:

```
Eastern
Western
UMass
MIT
```

I need to find out which university names *from the Excel sheet* do **not** exist in the SQL table. i.e. Filter the universities that ARE in the table out of the Excel sheet. e.g.:

```
UMass
MIT
```

If I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM university WHERE name IN ( 'Eastern', 'Western', 'UMass', 'MIT' )
```

I would get back:

```
2, Eastern
3, Western
```

But what I really what back is *the stuff in the spreadsheet* that wasn't in the table. e.g.:

```
UMass
MIT
```

I there any easy way to do this with an SQL query?

Comment: What part you have problem? Upload the excel to the DB? Want use the DB in excel? or make the comparasion between both tables?

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: First import excel column into table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html), then select from the new table with a not exists on the university table.

Comment: Again, the easy way is upload your excel sheet to mySql and then use it as a regular table. instead copuy/paste the names

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is upload your excel sheet in a db table and do a `LEFT JOIN`

[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/SSVA64426)

```
SELECT newUniv.name
FROM newUniv
LEFT JOIN University
  ON newUniv.name = University.name
WHERE University.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of laziness I would probably just paste the names from sql into a new sheet and use an excel formula to find out which ones are not in the database.

This returns `TRUE` when a value is not in the reference list.

```
=ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE))
```

Where `A2` is a name you are looking up and `Sheet2!A:A` is where you pasted the names from the database